# Pass special wildcards characters to set command

Tags: bash, wildcards, escape-characters

I would like to set variables with a special sign "*" using the "set" command

```
$ Q='A * B'
$ set -- $Q
$ echo "$1 $2 $3"
```

I expect "A * B"

Of course, it does not work as expected because an asterisk is a special sign

I tried:

```
$ Q='A \* B'
$ Q='A "*" B'
```

However, it is passed to `$2`

I've got `A \* B` and `A "*" B` instead of expected `A * B`

How to pass correctly this expression to set command?

Answer (score 1):

You should always quote the variables to prevent strange behavior. So use `set -- "Q"` in instead of just `set -- $Q`.

```
$ Q='A * B'
$ set -- "$Q"
$ echo "$1 $2 $3"
A * B
```

Comment: Note that $2 and $3 are empty in this case. Quoting `"$Q"` makes the contents to be a single word, retrieved by $1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Q to be 3 separate words, you have to use an array:

```bsh
Q=(A '*' B)
set -- "${Q[@]}"    # you must use this syntax to expand the array safely.
printf '%s\n' "$@"  # print the positional params on separate lines
```

```
A
*
B
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for more details.

Answer (score -1):

You have already been told how to solve the problem (I consider the array approach the better one). What's missing yet is an explanation.

Quoting (`"`, `'`, `\`) only works on the command line (i.e. if the shell parser encounters them literally). If it is part of a variable then it is just a string. Only globbing and word splitting characters are relevant within a variable.

The exception is that you use `eval` to take the content of a variable on the "command line level". But that is rarely a good idea.

```
Q='A "*" B'

echo $Q
A "*" B

eval echo $Q
A * B
```

Another option is to disable globbing:

```
Q='A * B'

set -f

echo $Q
A * B
```